# Using the raw camera byte[] array for augmented reality

Tags: android, image, image-processing, augmented-reality, android-camera

I'm developing an Augmented Reality app, so I need to capture the camera preview, add visual effects to it, and display it on screen. I would like to do this using the `onPreviewFrame` method of `PreviewCallback`. This gives me a `byte[]` variable containing raw image data (YUV420 encoded) to work with.

Even though I searched for a solution for many hours, I cannot find a way to convert this `byte[]` variable to any image format I can work with or even draw on the screen.

Preferably, I would convert the `byte[]` data to some RGB format that can be used both for computations and drawing.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same issue a few months back when I had to do some
edge detection on the camera frames. This works perfectly for me.
Try it out.

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format, int width,int height) 
        {
            camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

                    int width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
                    int height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;

                    ByteArrayOutputStream outstr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height); 
                    YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(data,ImageFormat.NV21,width,height,null);
                    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, outstr);
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outstr.toByteArray(), 0, outstr.size());
                }
}
}
```

You can use the bitmap for all your processing purposes now.
Get the interested pixel and you can comfortably do your RGB 
or HSV stuff on it.

Comment: Thanks! This is a clean and simple code that actually works. However, I get a frame rate of about 2 fps if I draw this bitmap to an ImageView. Any tips/suggestions on that?

Comment: Not much idea on that. I get very low fps too. But then your question reveals something for me. I assumed it was my edge detection that was taking time. I never thought drawing the bitmap to imageview could also be a slow-down factor.

Comment: Drawing the bitmap on the image view is not taking time, neither is the edge detection taking any considerable amount of time. The culprit here is the conversion from ByteArray to the Bitmap object.

Answer (score 7):

Imran Nazar has writen a two part tutorial on augmented reality which you may find useful. Although he eventually uses the NDK, the [first part](http://imrannazar.com/Augmented-Reality-with-the-Android-NDK:-Part-1) and most of the [second part](http://imrannazar.com/Augmented-Reality-with-the-Android-NDK:-Part-2) detail what you need using just Java.

I believe [Bitmap.createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29) is the method you need.

Comment: Thanks. I believe Nazar uses a preview and a bitmap drawing on top of the preview. Unfortunately, this can cause the overlay lagging behind the preview due to extra computation in comparison to the direct overlay. Or so I have read.

Comment: Perhaps, but his examples indicate how to apply matrices and create a Bitmap object.